# Alert me XamlCompiler error WMC1012 on building

Tags: c#, visual-studio, compiler-errors, csproj, building

I try to build a windows 10 universal App with Visual Studio in c# and xaml.

But I get the error:

```
[...].csproj : XamlCompiler error WMC1012: A project cannot have more than one ApplicationXaml item
```

What does it mean? I only have one App.xaml in my project.
Do you have a tip for me?

Answer (score 0):

This error now happens in VS 2022 when there is more than one *.appxmanifest file in the project.

This could happen when you want to have different manifests for each configuration. Possible solution: [Different/Multiple Package.appxmanifest File depending Upon different Configuration UWP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66237712/different-multiple-package-appxmanifest-file-depending-upon-different-configurat)