# Different/Multiple Package.appxmanifest File depending Upon different Configuration UWP

Tags: xamarin, uwp, xamarin.uwp

[image]

I have a Xamarin Project and have different configuration depending upon the type of release. I want to point to different Package.appxmanifest Depending upon my configuration. How can I achieve that.

Answer (score 0):

> Different/Multiple Package.appxmanifest File depending Upon different Configuration UWP

If you do want to use different `Package.appxmanifest` files for some build configurations. you could edit `yourproject.csproj` manually.

Right Click Project-> Unload Project-> Re-Right Click Project-> Edit Project.csproj file.

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Include="xxxxx_TemporaryKey.pfx" />
  <AppxManifest Include="Test.appxmanifest">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </AppxManifest>
</ItemGroup>
```

Find out the above `ItemGroup` node and reserve only one `AppxManifest`. And then modify the follow PropertyGroup node.

```
<PropertyGroup>
  <ApplicationManifest>Test.appxmanifest</ApplicationManifest>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For more please refer this [case reply](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47808922/xamarin-different-appxmanifest-files-for-different-build-configurations/47863443#47863443).

Comment: You mean remove this 
`<AppxManifest Include="Package.appxmanifest">
    <SubType>Designer</SubType>
  </AppxManifest>` and put this `<ApplicationManifest>Package.appxmanifest</ApplicationManifest>` In all configs? So I can have multiple files with different names in my proj?

Comment: I have edit the answer to make it clearly. you could have multiple files with different names, but Both ItemGroup and PropertyGroup have only one element.

Comment: I do not understand what you mean by reserve only one. Out of all the manifest file , I should only keep one in Item group and rest of them in Property Group? Is that it

Comment: Yep, keep only one AppxManifest element in the Itemgroup.